# Why can't I see my hotbar in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing yesterday and I might have pressed a button but my hotbar, hand and crosshair was gone. I pressed almost every button Imaginable and fixed nothing.
I pressed F1 and it only opens up windows explorer.
I play on windows 10 edition and never had this problem.
I waited a day to see if it would clear up and nothing happens.
I went on my other worlds and I have the same problem.

Comment: Are you using a laptop? You may need to press Fn + F1 instead of just F1>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open Minecraft
2. Go to "Settings"
3. Go to "Video"
4. Make sure "Hide Hud" Is turned OFF

[image: The video settings menu]